# Confusion about the adjoint of an outer product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

I am trying to show that $(| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)^\dagger = | \phi \rangle \langle \psi |$ without Dirac notation but I keep running into a wall. My procedure is as follows, where I use the defining property of the adjoint in the first equality and I "translate" away from Dirac notation in the second equality. For arbitrary $v_1,v_2 \in V$,
$$((| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)^\dagger v_1,v_2) \equiv (v_1,(| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)v_2) = (v_1,(\phi,v_2) \psi) = (\phi,v_2)(v_1, \psi) \stackrel{?}{=} ((\psi,v_1) \phi,v_2)\equiv((| \phi \rangle \langle \psi |) v_1,v_2)$$
which would be enough for the desired result, but I can't seem to manipulate the quantities in order to bridge the gap with the question mark (?). Can someone supply the details? I've tried
$$((| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)^\dagger v_1,v_2) \equiv (v_1,(| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)v_2) = (v_1,(\phi,v_2) \psi) = (\phi,v_2)(v_1, \psi) = (\phi,v_2)(\psi,v_1)^* = ((\phi,v_2)^*\psi,v_1)^* = \dots?$$
but can't see how that gets me anywhere.

Edit, maybe I see it now:
$$((| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)^\dagger v_1,v_2) \equiv (v_1,(| \psi \rangle \langle \phi |)v_2) = (v_1,(\phi,v_2) \psi) = (\phi,v_2)(v_1, \psi) =  ((v_1, \psi)^*\phi,v_2) = ((\psi,v_1)\phi,v_2)$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit is correct. Alternatively, you could have proved the question-marked equality by coming from the other side of your desired relation, i.e.
$$
((|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|)v_1,v_2) = ((\psi,v_1)\phi,v_2) = (\psi,v_1)^*(\phi,v_2) = (v_1,\psi)(\phi,v_2),
$$
which is what you have before the question mark, hence $((|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|)v_1,v_2) = ((|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)^\dagger v_1,v_2)$ and $|\phi\rangle\langle\psi| = (|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)^\dagger$.